# Posting two textbox values through ajax

Tags: java, php, ajax

I have some problem to post 2 items namely 'content', 'content1'. 'content' is successfully posted. But 'content1' is showing as undefined index. I have tried the below code. The lines containing 'content1' is made as comments line before posting here. Please indicate my mistakes.

```
$(function() {
$(".submit_button").click(function() {
var textcontent = $("#content").val();
//var textcontent1 = $("#content1").val();
var dataString = 'content='+ textcontent;
//var dataString1 = 'content1='+ textcontent1;
if(textcontent=='')
{
alert("Enter some text..");
$("#content").focus();
//$("#content1").focus();
}
else
{
$("#flash").show();
$("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<span class="load">Loading..</span>');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "action.php",
data: dataString,
// data1: dataString1,//dataString1,
cache: true,
success: function(html){
$("#show").after(html);
document.getElementById('content').value='';
//document.getElementById('content1').value='';
$("#flash").hide();
$("#content").focus();
//$("#content1").focus();
}  
});
}
return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Oof - you should really indent your code!

That said - in your current code, you have the following lines commented out:

```
//var textcontent1 = $("#content1").val();
//var dataString1 = 'content1='+ textcontent1;
```

Which, yeah, those things aren't being set.

Uncomment those, and then pass the data as an object, like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "action.php",
    data: {
        'dataString' : dataString,
        'dataString1' : dataString1,
    },
    cache: true,
    // etc.
```

action.php will then receive those two strings as `$_POST['dataString']` and `$_POST['dataString1']`.